# Вывод содержимого файла на консоль

Tags: c++

Имеется часть кода:

```
ofstream file1("list.txt");
FILE *f1, *f2;
    void addStudent() {
        f1 = fopen("list.txt", "wb");
        cout << "Enter the Name of student: ";
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        gets_s(Students.Name, 29);
        file1 << Students.Name<<" ";
        cout << "Enter the average ball: ";
        cin >> Students.ball;
        file1 << "Av - " << Students.ball << " \n";
        fclose(f1);
    }

    void showGroup() {
        f1 = fopen("list.txt", "rb");
        cout << "\t\tInformation" << endl;
        ifstream fin("list.txt");
        string buf;
        while (getline(fin, buf)) {
            cout << buf << endl;
        }
        fclose(f1);
    }
```

Задача - добавление данных в файл, а после их вывод на консоль. Однако при выполнении функции showGroup() выводится только строка "Information". В чём проблема?

Comment: Что-то у вас не то. Создаете файл через `fopen`, а пишете не пойми куда (что такое `file1`??) как `file1 << `. Одновременно открываете файл разными способами... Ощущение от вашего кода - попытка пройти одновременно через 2 двери.

Comment: Harry, извиняюсь, не до конца скопировал. Добавил часть кода

Comment: А в файле случайно не кириллические символы?

Answer (score 1):

Попробовал запустить у себя ваш код.

```
ofstream file1("list.txt");
ifstream fin("list.txt");
```

Вы пытаетесь дважды открыть один и тот же файл, отсюда и ошибка. Если убрать создание file1, то ваш код выводит содержимое файла. Еще вызывает вопрос вот эта строчка:

```
f1 = fopen("list.txt", "rb");
```

На работоспособность она не повлияла, но непонятен смысл создания f1, когда вы его не используете. Если хотите в одной функции проводить и чтение и запись, то вам придется делать это по очереди.

Comment: Timur Yalimov, а как тогда без ifstream fin("list.txt"); считать данные из файла?

Comment: Вам как раз и надо оставить fin, с ним проблем нет.  Вам необходимо убрать ofstream file1("list.txt"), чтобы fin смог считывать данные. Если в этой же функции вы захотите в последствии еще что-то записывать файл, то вы делаете fin.close(), открываете ofstream file1("list.txt"), записываете данные, закрываете.